# Why is UMASK setting in /etc/login.defs not honoured?

Tags: linux, pam, umask

I have the `UMASK` setting in /etc/login.defs set to 077, but when I log in and query it, I get this:

```
$ umask
0007
```

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that in modern Linux distros, [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM)'s pam_umask.so module controls reading the `UMASK` setting from /etc/login.defs .  However, it tweaks the value used under certain circumstances, as described by [pam_umask(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_umask):

> The PAM module tries to get the umask value from the following places
>   in the following order:
>
> ·   `umask=` argument
>
> ·   `umask=` entry in the user's GECOS field
>
> ·   `UMASK=` entry from /etc/default/login
>
> ·   `UMASK` entry from /etc/login.defs (influenced by `USERGROUPS_ENAB` in
>         /etc/login.defs)

See /etc/pam.d/common-session on an Ubuntu host to see how `pam_umask.so` is invoked.

According to a comment in /etc/login.defs:

> If USERGROUPS_ENAB is set to "yes", that will modify this UMASK default value
>   for private user groups, i. e. the uid is the same as gid, and username is
>   the same as the primary group name: for these, the user permissions will be
>   used as group permissions, e. g. 022 will become 002.

Therefore it is considered standard behaviour.  I'd recommend against disabling `USERGROUPS_ENAB` because that will stop the creation of a corresponding group upon user creation.  To forcibly set the umask without changing this behaviour, create /etc/default/login containing `UMASK=077` and comment out `UMASK  077` in /etc/login.defs .

(PAM = Pluggable Authentication Modules)

Comment: Your `/etc/default/login` method sounds elegant, but didn't do it for me (maybe the machine needs a reboot for that?). I ended up creating a small shell script in `/etc/profile.d/` calling `umask 002`. (setting `UMASK=002` there did also not work)

Comment: I agree with @florian. On CentOS 7 , `/etc/profile` explicitly set umask to 002 (if `uid > 199` and `uid = gid`) or 022. The only way to bypass it is to override it with a script in `/etc/profile.d`.  What you describe seems to work on debian like distributions only. On CentOS 7, pam_umask is not used.

Answer (score -2):

The umask value in /etc/login.defs is only used when creating a user and is applied to the user's home directory

The default umask for a user is determined in /etc/profile. (Does not apply in Debian based distributions)

You may change a specific users umask in  ~/.bash_profile

I also believe USERGROUPS_ENAB=yes enforces UPG (Universal Private Group) and does not have any affect on the umask value.  (I could be wrong)

Comment: You mentioned that the /etc/login.defs setting is only used when creating a user.  This is not what I read in the pam_umask(8) manual quoted in my answer.  What's your reference for this?